# Prove the equation is a solution to the second order ODE (Bessel's Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, bessel-functions

The given equation is 
$$x^2y^{''}+xy^{'}+(x^2-\frac{1}{4})y=0$$

and the solution we are meant to verify is 
$$y_1(x)=x^{-1/2}\cos(x)$$
Taking the first and second derivative of this solution yields 
$$y^{'}_1(x)=-\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\cos(x)}{2x^{3/2}}$$
$$y^{''}_1(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{3/2}}+\frac{\cos(x)}{3x^{5/2}}+\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{3/2}}$$
Now substituting in these derivative into their respective spots
$$0=x^2\left(-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}}+\frac{\cos(x)}{3x^{5/2}}\right)+x\left(-\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\cos(x)}{2x^{3/2}}\right)+(x^2-\frac{1}{4})\left(x^{-1/2}\cos(x)\right)$$
What I got as a final answer was $$-3x^{-1/2}\cos(x)\ne0$$

Am I correct or did I make a fault along the way?

Answer (score 1):

This is good:
$$y'_1(x)=-\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\cos(x)}{2x^{3/2}}$$
But this line is not correct:
$$y''_1(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{3/2}}+\color{red}{\frac{\cos(x)}{3x^{5/2}}}+\frac{\sin(x)}{2x^{3/2}}$$
It should be:
$$y''_1(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\color{blue}{\dfrac 34\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{5/2}}}+\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}}$$